# Reactjs TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined when reading params from url

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two pages, one for search and one for results. In the search page you submit a form with the search item which is then passed in the url. In results page I try to read that parameter and pass it as a variable to a function I have there, however I keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined`

Here's my search page:

```
class Search extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      search: ''
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    const data = this.state
    this.props.history.push('/search/' + data.search);
  }

  handleInputChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    const {search} = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <p>What are you searching for?</p>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <p><input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="search" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></input></p>
          <p><button>Search!</button></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then in the results page I have this code:

```
function Result() {


  const ListLoading = withListLoading(List);
  const [appState, setAppState] = useState({
    loading: false,
    products: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setAppState({ loading: true });
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/"
    const searchItem = this.props.params.search
    let urls = [];
    const allUrls = shops.map((shop) => {
      let url = baseUrl + searchItem;
      urls.push(url)
    });

    function fetchData() {
      const allRequests = urls.map(url =>
        fetch(url).then(response => response.json())
      );
      return Promise.all(allRequests);
    };

    fetchData().then(arrayOfResponses => 
      setAppState({loading: false, products: arrayOfResponses}),
    );
  }, [setAppState]);
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Products</h1>
      </div>
      <div className='repo-container'>
        <ListLoading isLoading={appState.loading} products={appState.products} />
      </div>
      <footer>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Result;
```

The function will make a call to another application I have running on localhost.
I set the variable `const searchItem = this.props.params.search` but that doesn't seem to work.

How else can I read the param from the url and make it a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props are passed as an argument to function components. You can’t access them via “this”:

```js
function Result (props) {
  // do stuff with props, not this.props
}
```

---

Another observation that might be an issue:

Change `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}` to `onSubmit={e => this.handleSubmit(e)}`

The issue is that when you invoke a method on an object, the scope (what “this” represents while inside the function) is set to the object on which the method was invoked. So when you do:

```js
this.handleSubmit()
```

…inside the handleSubmit function “this” is (still) your component.

But if you detach it and invoke it on its own as a regular function:

```js
const fn = this.handleSubmit;
fn() // “this” isn’t set; it’s undefined inside the function
```

The scope gets lost. So when you then try to do `this.props` it blows up, because “this” is undefined.

Comment: I did and I'm still getting the error after being redirected to `/search` page

Comment: I got it to work. One more thing I had to change was how I define the variable. `const searchItem = props.match.params.search` is how the param is being read now. Thanks a lot Ray